# reactivemongo with scala3, pekko, play-3

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-3, reactivemongo

Is it possible to use reactivemongo with scala3, pekko and play-3.0.1?
The reactivemongo documentation suggests adding a dependency to

```
"org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo-pekko" % "1.0"
```

but that seems to be out of date. I would like to use the latest version (1.1.0-RC12).
There is also a "reactivemongo-actors-pekko" dependency available, but not for scala3.

Comment: Can you be more precise on what you want to do that you cannot? We're using ReactiveMongo with Play 3 and Pekko but not Scala 3 for instance, but I don't think we use any of the provided integration with neither Play nor Pekko. Thus, yes ReactiveMongo can work in this context but sounds like it cannot in yours, which is why I think it needs clarifications on your expected usage.

Comment: I also tried with Scala-2.13 and got this error: 

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'akka.actor.ActorSystem$ reactivemongo.actors.actor.package$.ActorSystem()'
        at reactivemongo.api.AsyncDriver.<init>(AsyncDriver.scala:80)

The dependencies include:

reactivemongo,
reactivemongo-actors-pekko,
reactivemongo-play-json-compat

Using version 1.1.0-RC12.

Comment: OK, I found the problem: I needed to use this version of reactivemongo: "org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo"                  % "1.1.0.pekko-RC12"

Comment: 1.1.0.pekko-RC12 needs a playframework version at play3-reactivemongo.